# Script not working on windows 7

Tags: vbscript

I am working on a VBScript where it activates an application, sends a password to that application and minimizes the application. My script fails sending the keys. The application does not get the password, but when I double-click on the script it receives the password and minimizes. I don't know where the error is.

It's called like this:

`InitliszeUSb.bat`:

```
pause
START %myDrive%"RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe" 
pushd %~dp0
ping 10.10.10.10 -n 1 -w 10000 >nul
start /b "" cscript "D:\min.vbs"
```

`Min.vbs`:

```
Option Explicit
Dim oSHL : Set oSHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oSHL.AppActivate "SanDisk SecureAccess"
oSHL.SendKeys "pass1_word~" 'Enters Password
WScript.Sleep(3000)
oSHL.SendKeys "% n" 'Minimises the window
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Did you try putting a delay *before* sending the password? Also, you say that the script works when double-clicked, so under which circumstances does it fail to work? BTW, note that `SendKeys` is a *terrible* way of automating things and should be avoided unless someone's forcing you at gunpoint.

Comment: HI Ansgar it fails to work  under calling from a batch script.

Comment: What is the `start /b ""` supposed to achieve? Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, I experienced issues when using `SendKeys` to send keys to other apps (the way like you do), **when `SendKeys` is not running in elevated process.** Sometimes the macro/script works 100%, sometimes it looks like keystrokes are getting lost. The only way around I found for that was running sender application (or script) elevated (i.e. "As Administrator").